# Is it possible to dynamically change view type in a RecyclerView?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with 2 types of views and i want to change a single item view of type 1 in the recycler view to type 2, when an event is fired.

Here is the code for creating view holders

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View itemView = null;
    ItemViewHolder vh = null;
    switch (viewType) {
    case FILE_UPLOADING:
        itemView = LayoutInflater.From (parent.Context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.ItemCardViewUploading, parent, false);
        vh = new UploadingItemViewHolder (itemView, OnClick, OnItemMenuClick);
        break;
    case FILE_DEFAULT:
        itemView = LayoutInflater.From (parent.Context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.ItemCardView, parent, false);
        vh = new ItemViewHolder (itemView, OnClick, OnItemMenuClick);
        break;
    }

    return vh;
}
```

When an `UploadingItemViewHolder` is created, a file is being uploaded and when the upload is done, an event is fired and i want to change the appearance of the item that was initially added with `UploadingItemViewHolder` to look like default `ItemViewHolder`.

Is it possible to change the type of view dynamically or do i have to remove the old item and add a new item?

**Edit:**

GetItemViewType() method:

```
public override int GetItemViewType (int position)
{
    if (itemList [position].Hash == null) //If hash is null, then the item upload is in progress
        return FILE_UPLOADING;
    return FILE_DEFAULT;
}
```

Comment: yes you can....on uploading fire notifyDataSetChange() method and in onBindViewHolder() respond accordingly

Comment: @HRaval could you write an example?

Comment: post your getView() method

Comment: @HRaval I don't have a getView() method

Comment: sorry i mean getItemViewType()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside onBindViewHolder()

```
if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {
   //data with itemviewholder
}else{
 //uploading items
}
```

when your uploading is completed

```
 itemList [position].Hash = new Hash(); //to make it not null
 adaper.notifyItemChanged(position);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest another approach : [`ViewSwitcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) is meant to handle switching between two views (for more than two, use [`ViewFlipper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html)) so you could define a single type and a single ViewHolder, and define your items as `ViewSwitcher`s. You then only have to trigger the switch when upload is finished.

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
  ViewSwitcher itemView = new ViewSwitcher(parent.Context);
  itemView.addView(LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.ItemCardViewUploading, parent, false), 0, null);
  itemView.addView(LayoutInflater.From (parent.Context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.ItemCardView, parent, false), 0, null);
  return new ItemViewHolder(itemView, OnClick, OnItemMenuClick);
}

// you may want to change parameter to fit the way you identify your file
public void onUploadCompleted(long itemId)
{
  ItemViewHolder vh = (ItemViewHolder) findViewHolderForItemId(itemId);
  ((ViewSwitcher) vh.itemView).showNext();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with RecyclerView and both the remove and the update work well.

1. REMOVE: There are 4 steps to remove an item from a RecyclerView

   - `list.remove(position);`
   - `recycler.removeViewAt(position);`
   - `mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);`
   - `mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());`

These line of codes work for me.

2. UPDATE THE DATA: The only things I had to do is

   - `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

You had to do all of this in the Activity/Fragment code not in the RecyclerView Adapter code.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You try this implementation in your adapter:

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        int inputtype =0;

        if(position ==0)
        {
            inputtype =1;
        }
        else
        {
            inputtype =2;

        }

        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType==1)
        {
            View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.layout1, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder1(view); 
        }
        else
        {
            View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.layout2, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder2(view);  

        }

    }
```